# Python - Proper way of inheritance, super and initialize object (selenium, phantomjs)

Tags: python, inheritance, selenium, phantomjs

I wrote pretty simple code, but I want to know is it proper way to resolve problem:

```
from selenium import webdriver


class MyClass(webdriver.PhantomJS):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        phantomjs_path = 'node_modules/.bin/phantomjs'
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(phantomjs_path)

        super().__init__(phantomjs_path, *args, **kwargs)
```

I created class, which inherit from `selenium.webdriver.PhantomJS` - of course I execute `super()`. Additionaly I create object `self.driver`.

Can/Should I *combine* last two lines in one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd not use the second-last line at all. You are creating *another instance* inside your subclass there. `self.driver` is basically the same thing as `self` now, only without your extra methods.

Omit it altogether:

```
class MyClass(webdriver.PhantomJS):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        phantomjs_path = 'node_modules/.bin/phantomjs'
        super().__init__(phantomjs_path, *args, **kwargs)
```

In your method, `self` is the instance already.